Name of convention of romanized vowel pronunciation ("pronounce like Spanish")?
In the romanization of various languages—very, very roughly speaking—the vowel letters a, e, i, o, and u are intended to be read like in Spanish or Italian. Does this convention have a name?
EDIT The motivation of this question:
Although it's true the "convention" I asked for is "the default", as Janus Bahs Jacquet in the comment, most lay persons do not to seem to be aware of this fact, and too much influenced by English. As a consequence many romanized words are not read, uh, "as intended".
Of course the situation is not so simple; dipthongs, vowel letters in row, exceeptions—it's in fact impossible to tell how to read pronouns of the languages you don't know.
More rationale:
Draconis refers to it as the "IPA pronunciation" (in the answer below) - this fact indicates that in fact a name has to exist (for convenience), but it is not widely known.

That’s roughly how those letters are pronounced in the majority of languages that use Latin-based alphabet, with some relatively minor variation such as [æ ~ a ~ ɑ], [e ~ ε], [ɪ ~ i], [o ~ ɔ], [ʊ ~ u]. It’s English that’s the outlier here, not Spanish or Italian. As such, I don’t think there’s a specific name for it, just like I don’t think there’s a name for pronouncing ⟨b f m⟩ like [b f m] – that’s just their most common, ‘default’ pronunciation.

The separate vowels (letters) are one thing; their use in words is another.

This brief grammar of Interlingua (https://www.interlingua.com/archivos/en/Short%20Interlingua%20grammar%20and%20vocabulary.pdf) calls this a component of "continental" pronunciation.

Pronunciation: The pronunciation in general is “continental” (vowels are as in Spanish, Italian and German; c before e, i, y is pronounced as s or ts, otherwise as k;
th is pronounced as t and ph as f, etc.).


This is not a specific convention but it's how the letters have always been pronounced since the Latin alphabet was developed. Sound changes in languages like English and French have simply caused those languages to use different values for the letters. In fact Old English texts like Bēowulf use those letters for largely the same sounds as Spanish, contrary to Modern English.

That's how those letters are used in the International Phonetic Alphabet, so I've referred to it before as "the IPA pronunciation".

That does not seem recommendable as it beckons questions like whether [ä], [ɛ], [e̞], etc. fall within the "IPA pronunciation" and how much deviation from the cardinal values you're willing to permit.

assuming you want a phrase that summarizes such pronunciations of vowels, “vowels are as in IPA” could work.
